# Hidden template field value not avaialble on server Side

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on Asp.net and stuck in middle.
I have a gridview with template field.Gridview have 3 columns and I want to pass value of two columns to server Side.

**Scenario**-On Clicking lnkRemove(LinkButton),the GUID should be passed(which is getting passed in Command arguement) and also the value of *SEQ_NBR* column(passing this value is problem for me)
I am trying with Hidden field but how to get hiiden field value in Server Side code(i.e `Deletedata`).

**Code**

```
<asp:GridView>
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "SEQ_NBR">
        <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" 
             Value='<%# Eval("SEQ_NBR") %>' />  
            <asp:Label ID="SEQ_NBR" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("SEQ_NBR")%>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="SEQ_NBR" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text="Auto generated"></asp:Label>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRemove" runat="server"
            CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("GUID")%>'
         OnClientClick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete?')" 
        Text = "Delete" OnClick = "Deletedata"></asp:LinkButton>

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my server side code  is:

```
 protected void Deletedata(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
//I want Hiddden field value here;I tried below code but not working.Any suggestion .
chkSelect = GridView.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("HiddenField1");
        }
```

Comment: Is `Deletedata` actually `DeleteRecipdata`?

Comment: Oh Sorry.I corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use

```
GridView.Controls[0].Controls[0].FindControl("HiddenField1");
```

but on the `GridViewRow` since that is the `NamingContainer`:

```
GridView.Rows[0].FindControl("HiddenField1");
```

But in this case you want to find the hiddenfield from the LinkButton's click-event. Therefore use following approach. The LinkButton's `NamingContainer` is the `GridViewRow`:

```
protected void Deletedata(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton) sender;
   GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) lnkRemove.NamingContainer;
   HiddenField hf =  (HiddenField) row.FindControl("HiddenField1");
   string seqNbr = hf.Value; // voilà
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
        GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        GridView.SelectedIndex = row.RowIndex;
        var HiddenField= GridView.Rows[gridMain.SelectedIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1") as HtmlInputHidden;      
        if (HiddenField!= null)
        {
            sting strValue = HiddenField.Value;
        }
```